# what does it mean to raise the set of integers (or any set) to a power N

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know this is a fairly simple answer, but I can't seem to find an easy example.

What does $\mathbb{Z}^N$ mean? or even $\mathbb{Z}^{n \times N}$?  And what would sampling from this set look like?

To clarify, $N$ and $n$ are natural numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: $A^B$ with $A$ and $B$ as sets is the collection of functions with domain $B$ and codomain $A$.  By convenience of notation, we have that $|A^B|=|A|^{|B|}$.  Specifically here, $\Bbb Z^{\Bbb N}$ is the collection of functions from the set of natural numbers to the integers... in other words, the collection of infinite sequences of integers.  If you intended $N$ to be a specific natural number rather than the set of natural numbers, then this is the set of sequences of length $N$ containing integers.

Comment: You are assuming $N$ refers to the set of natural numbers. That is nowhere in the question @JMoravitz

Comment: Especially since OP's question has the correct $\mathbb Z$ for integers but not $\mathbb N$ for natural numbers. @JMoravitz

Comment: In general, $A^B$ is the set of all functions from $B$ to $A.$ If $N$ is a natural number, then $A^N=A^{[N]}$ where $[N]=\{1,2,3,\dots,N\}.$ Often $A^{m\times n}$ means $m\times n$ matrices with entries in $A,$ which is equivalent to functions from $[m]\times[n]\to A.$

Comment: i have updated the Q to show $N$ and $n$ are natural numbers rather than the set itself.